# How to search for Nearby Places with both Radius and rank=distance in iOS

Tags: ios, google-places-api, distance, rank, radius

As per Google Places API, I cannot search for nearby places using both Radius and rank=distance filters in place. Has anyone come up with alternate ways to tackle this issue?

```
var urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=\(coordinate.latitude),\(coordinate.longitude)&radius=\(radius)&rankby=distance&sensor=true&key=\(googleAPIKey)"
```

Comment: provide trial code..

Comment: added. Please check

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Instead, I used `radius=` to get all the nearby places and then sorted in ascending order by distance from user location using `array.sorted(:by` method